# Unable to store data from my table into a hash map in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to store all Patient full names into a hash map from my database table however I am getting the following error :

```
param is missing or the value is empty: patient
```

on this line in my patients controller:

```
def patient_params
      params.require(:patient).permit(:Full_Name, :Age, :Sex, :Address, :PPS, :Medical_Card)
end
```

I am unsure where I am going wrong with this, any help would be greatly appreciated!

patients_controller.rb

```
  def allP
    # print out all
    p=Hash.new
    current_user.patients.all.each do |patient|
        p.store("Full Name", patient.Full_Name)
    end
  end
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= button_to "Some Button", :method=> "allP" %>
```

Error Log

```
Started POST "/patients?method=allP" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-03-14 00:36:54 +0000
Processing by PatientsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"lo2SRaVmEAHUdpqgknqT9iKPijEypaJ+8PX5Ad1igd/VTBbnRWsZy7akIVBx9c3eQnEmh6lljGm1sfEIDNs4Eg==", "met

hod"=>"allP"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1
]]
  ↳ /Users/j/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Completed 400 Bad Request in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)



ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: patient):

app/controllers/patients_controller.rb:83:in `patient_params'
app/controllers/patients_controller.rb:37:in `create'
```

Comment: However you're sending them, they don't have the "shape" you're application is asking for. It should be something like `{ patient: { full_name: ..., age: ... } }`

Comment: Right I think I am getting what your saying, because patient is expecting to have all these attributes I should define these within the hash map?

Comment: If you add your server output (where the submitted params are shown) to your question (using the `edit` link underneath the tags), it would be much easier to point out what the problem is. But, the short answer is probably that your form is malformed.

Comment: Where do I get the server output?

Comment: From your console where you're running your application.

Comment: Course, added it there

Comment: By looking at your parameters, it looks like you don't have a form for patient

Comment: @Jordans your `button_to` hits the CRUD `create` action and its option `:method` only accepts [symbols of HTTP verb](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to). You should change it by a `link_to` helper: `<%= link_to "Some Button", action: "allP" %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out those parameters (formatted for readability):

```
Started POST "/patients?method=allP" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-03-14 00:36:54 +0000
Processing by PatientsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {
    "authenticity_token"=>"lo2SRaVmEAHUdpqgknqT9iKPijEypaJ+8PX5Ad1igd/VTBbnRWsZy7akIVBx9c3eQnEmh6lljGm1sfEIDNs4Eg==", 
    "method"=>"allP"
  }
```

So, when you say:

```
def patient_params
  params.require(:patient).permit(:Full_Name, :Age, :Sex, :Address, :PPS, :Medical_Card)
end
```

`params.require(:patient)` fails because, wait for it, `params` doesn't include `:patient` and you, well, `require`d it.